# How to deserialize StringBuilder using jackson ObjectMapper

Tags: jackson, objectmapper

Following is the json i am trying to deserialize using objectMapper

```
{
  "myStringBuilder" : "mine"
}
```

Following is the POJO

```
public class MyPojo {

    private StringBuilder myStringBuilder;

    public MyPojo() {

    }

    public MyPojo(String myStringBuilder) {
        this.myStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(myStringBuilder);
    }

    public StringBuilder getMyStringBuilder() {
        return myStringBuilder;
    }

    public void setMyStringBuilder(StringBuilder myStringBuilder) {
        this.myStringBuilder = myStringBuilder;
    }

}
```

During Deserialization facing the following issue -

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
>   instantiate value of type [simple type, class java.lang.StringBuilder]
>   from String value ('mine'); no single-String constructor/factory
>   method  at [Source: {   "myStringBuilder" : "mine" }; line: 2, column:
>   3] (through reference chain:MyPojo["myStringBuilder"])

Please help me fixing this issue.

Comment: There is single-String constructor, I ran your code and it works fine.

Comment: You mean, the POJO is deserializable and you could not reproduce the error?

Comment: exactly. the constructor with `String` arg is called

Comment: mapper.withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE))
The above line I had to add for some of my business objects to work with serailization and deserailization. This line is causing the issue. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: still working.  it is working even when I completely delete the the constructor with String arg (only no-arg constructor)